# How to convert first letter of a sentence to lower case in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Can someone help me to convert only the first letter in the sentence to capital without affecting the case for the rest of the words

```
example: Phadiatop infant IgE Ab, QN, serum
Desired output: phadiatop infant IgE Ab, QN, serum
```

Tried `lower()` and LEN but converts the other letters too to lower case

Comment: What you are looking for is commonly referred to as title case.

Answer (score 2):

`=LOWER(LEFT(A1,1)) & MID(A1, 2, LEN(A1) - 1)`

Comment: Yes, nice. If you want to use dodgy code-golf, you can limit this to `=LOWER(LEFT(A1))&MID(A1,2,LEN(A1))`

Answer (score 0):

You could use `REPLACE()` to do an in-string conversion:

[image]

Formula in `B1`:

```
=REPLACE(A1,1,1,LOWER(LEFT(A1)))
```